# Can I have a column capable of keeping all types in MySQL (MariaDB)?

Tags: mysql, types, entity-attribute-value, mariadb, dynamic-columns

I have a few tables, for which I want to be able to offer a full amendment history for all rows. A brute force implementation would be to create a shadow table (i.e., shadow tables having identical column setup to the regular table) for each regular table where old entries go, and only keep the most recent entry in the regular table.

But I want to do it a little bit more efficiently. I want to have one table keeping all amendments for all tables. At the very most basic, its columns would be `table, column, value`. When a row is changed in a table, the old value of the changed column gets inserted into this table.

The problem with this new implementation is that the value column would need to be capable of keeping all types as different columns have different types.

Is there a way to create column capable of keeping all types?

I am using MariaDB 10.0.3 on a Debian Wheezy box.

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB has the capability of storing columns per row. They can be of arbitrary types. Could it satisfy what you try to achieve? Check https://kb.askmonty.org/en/dynamic-columns/. I didn't use it personally.